# I can't run Docker ToolBox on Windows 7

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I can't start docker toolbox on windows 7.
This are few steps i did.

1) I download Docker Toolbox from official site.

2) Installed it

3)Installed virtualbox.exe from docker directory.

4) When i run QUICKSTART DOCKER TERMINAL i get this after few settings:
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Setting env´... Press any key to continue...

So i can't run it. What shall i d0? 
Also i can't start start.sh

I can see docker --version from git,cmd, and created by docker in vb linux.
Also i can run hello-world from linux console from vb.
But how can i start docker?

Basically i don't understand where i need to work with docker from.

From my windows termianl or only from vb linux terminal

Comment: still can't resolve dat

Answer (score 2):

run as administrator a `cmd` and run this command

`"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"`

Answer (score 0):

it will be from your vb linux terminal.. everything is present inside it to run your docker.
the purpose of toolbox is to use it on the unsupported version on your machine via the virtual box..